# python re.sub(): difficulty with special characters (maybe?)

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use re.sub to turn this:

```
string = '\\(2 \\, e^{\\left(2 \\, x\\right)} \\sin\\left(2 \\, x\\right) + 2 \\, e^{\\left(2 \\, x\\right)} \\cos\\left(2 \\, x\\right)\\)'
```

into this:

```
'\\(2 \\, e^{2 \\, x} \\sin\\left(2 \\, x\\right) + 2 \\, e^{2 \\, x} \\cos\\left(2 \\, x\\right)\\)'
```

This is my best attempt, but it does not work:

```
re.sub(r'(?P<left-edge>e\^{\\left\()(?P<input>.*)(?P<right-edge>\\right\)})','e^{\g<input>}',string)

Note that <input> needs to handle an arbitrary expression, while <left-edge> and <right-edge> are fixed character strings.
```

I am assuming it has to do with the special characters involved, but several dozen attempts demonstrate that it is beyond my expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslashes in regular expressions must be escaped. You used `r''` so they do not have to be escaped as characters in Python string, but that's not enough for them to be interpreted as literal `\` chars in regexes. Use double backslashes:

```
re.sub(r'(?Pe\^{\\left()(?P.*)(?P\\right)})','e\^{\\g}',string)
```

Were it not for `r''`, they would have to be escaped **twice**, i.e. quadrupled, in order to satisfy both Python interpreter and regexp engine:

```
    re.sub('(?Pe\\^{\\\\left()(?P.*)(?P\\\\right)})','e\\^{\\\\g}',string)
```

(Additionally, you also forgot to escape one of `^` carets. I corrected that in both of my examples.)

Comment: the expressions are not even valid regexs. [And it doesn't work even if you fix the syntax errors](http://ideone.com/V4Fpi). You need `.*?` instead of `.*` as in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9548430/4279)

Answer (score 0):

`.*` matches too much:

```
print(re.sub(r'e\^{\\left\((.*?)\\right\)}', r'e^{\1}', s))
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/kMxYn)

```
\(2 \, e^{2 \, x} \sin\left(2 \, x\right) + 2 \, e^{2 \, x} \cos\left(2 \, x\right)\)
```